# Python threading not waiting - could be related to OO design issue

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

To my mind, I have a fairly simple long-IO operation that could be refined using threading.  I've built a DearPyGui GUI interface (not explicitly related to the problem - just background info). A user can load a file via the package's file loader. Some of these files can be quite large (3 GB). Therefore, I'm adding a pop-up window to lock the interface (modal) whilst the file is loading. The above was context, and the problem is not the DearPyGUI.

I'm starting a thread inside a method of a class instance, which in turn calls (via being the thread's target) a further method (from the same object) and then updates an attribute of that object, which is to be interrogated later. For example:

```
class IOClass:

    __init__(self):
        self.fileObj = None


    def loadFile(self, fileName):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.threadMethod, args=fileName)
        thread.start()
        #Load GUI wait-screen
        thread.join()

        #anything else..EXCEPTION THROWN HERE
        print(" ".join(["Version:", self.fileObj.getVersion()]))

    def threadMethod(self, fileName):
        print(" ".join(["Loading filename", fileName]))
        #expensive-basic Python IO operation here
        self.fileObj = ...python IO operation here
    
class GUIClass:

    __init__(self):
        pass

    def startMethod(self):
        #this is called by __main__
        ioClass = IOClass()
        ioClass.loadFile("filename.txt")
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (loadFile):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anthony/anaconda3/envs/CPRD-software/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/anthony/anaconda3/envs/CPRD-software/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: AnalysisController.loadFile() takes 2 positional arguments but 25 were given
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anthony/CPRD-software/GUI/Controllers/AnalysisController.py", line 117, in loadStudySpace
    print(" ".join(["Version:", self.fileObj.getVersion()]))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getVersion'
```

I'm not sure what's going on. The machine should sit there for at least 3 minutes as the data is loaded. But instead, it appears to perform `join`, but the main thread doesn't wait for the IO thread to load the file, instead attempting to class a method on what was loaded in.

Comment: `self.fileObj` is `None` so it has no attribute `getVersion()`, you set `self.fileObj` to `None` in the `__init__()` function

Comment: also why are you creating a thread if you use `.join()` right after you create it, just call the function if you don't do anything while the thread is running

Comment: self.fileObj is None, yep, but then it is populated in the thread's target method threadMethod. Also, please consider that this is a reduced example. I do not call .join immediately after. In the real code, which I can't share, other operations happen in the main thread between start() and join().

Comment: Ditto what @OmerDagry said. If you `join()` a thread immediately after you `start()` it, that completely negates any benefit you would get by creating the thread. Your `loadFile()` function might as well just call `threadFunction()` itself instead of creating a new thread to call it. The only reason for creating a thread is if the caller is going to do something else, concurrently with the thread, after starting it and before joining it.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I am not executing join() immediately after start(). This is a reduced example, but I understand that the comment between start and join wasn't accurate so I've edited my question..

Comment: You should answer your own question, instead of adding the answer to the question. It's a rule. Also, the question will not be exposed to one who filters only not answered questions.

Comment: @relent95 done. I do love rules...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. In the threading.Thread() do not call the method using self. Instead, pass self in as an argument to the thread method e.g.,

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=threadMethod, args=(self, fileName))
```

The target function doesn't change i.e. it remains as so:

```
def threadMethod(self, fileName):
    #expensive-basic Python IO operation here
    self.fileObj = ...python IO operation here
```